# Time.deltaTime Unity3D not adding properly with high numbers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My previous post has been closed even though my problem has not been resolved - thus another try at explaining what happens.

Currently, the code below works - there is nothing ambiguous happening. Although, whenever the **distance** variable increases to high values, lets say 1000000, the addition at the bottom of the code does not represent what should actually happen. Small values of variable **baseSpeed** are ignored by that addition and I have no clue why that happens.

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

float baseSpeed = 0;
float distance = 0;

public TextMeshProUGUI speedText;
public TextMeshProUGUI distanceText;

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        baseSpeed += 0.1f;
    }

    speed = baseSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    distance += speed;

    speedText.text = ((baseSpeed)).ToString() + "m/s";
    distanceText.text = ((distance)).ToString() + "m";
}
```

Testing cases:

**distance** = 100 (works)

**distance** = 1000000 (stops working for **baseSpeed** 0 - 2)

Comment: I would recommend looking at how floating point values work in memory:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215065/can-anyone-explain-representation-of-float-in-memory

Comment: The first answer should be able to help significantly... simplified explanation is the higher your whole number value, the less decimals you can accurately represent.   that answer explains that way more in depth.

Comment: @AresCaelum I specified that its a float number in the declaration, yet it cant calculate float values?

Comment: you said it works fine for 100, and stops working for 1000000.  That is because the higher your whole number the less bits it has to represent the floating values.  read the answer on that post.

Comment: @AresCaelum yeah I read that - back to the question, what am I supposed to do in such case?

Comment: I understand now how it works, thanks for that.

Comment: There are bigger floating point values then float: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types  there are also number libraries you can use for such cases.

Comment: @Ruzihm yes! thanks everyone!